# Getting many OpenGL Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opengl

I'm trying to compile someone else's project, and I'm getting about 850 errors all related to OpenGL. I'm using Visual Studio 2008, on 64-bit Windows 7, but the project is a Win32 project.

As you can see, the errors below are from `gl.h` in the Windows SDK include folder under `Program Files`, not `Program Files (x86)` so I'm guessing that's part of the problem. I've tried adding the .NET 2003 include directory which has gl.h and is under `Program Files (x86)`, but it's still trying to use the version of gl.h under `Program Files`.

Also, the project uses wxWidgets 2.4.2 and I can't find any instance of `gl.h` being included in the solution itself, so I'm not sure what's pulling it in.

Update: Still unable to compile this. The actual project I'm trying to compile is the "[Interactive Digital Photomontage](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/photomontage/release/)" tool (source code at the link). They include a VS2003 project file and instructions, which I followed carefully. I even tried building in VS2003 and got the same errors. I'm curious if anyone has a moment to try this on their system and see if they get the same errors. Requires wxWidgets 2.4.2 to be installed.

Any thoughts? I've included a sample of some of the errors below. Thanks.

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include\GL/gl.h(1152) : error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include\GL/gl.h(1152) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include\GL/gl.h(1152) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'glAccum'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include\GL/gl.h(1152) : error C2182: 'APIENTRY' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include\GL/gl.h(1152) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include\GL/gl.h(1153) : error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include\GL/gl.h(1153) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include\GL/gl.h(1153) : error C2086: 'int WINGDIAPI' : redefinition
```

Comment: Header files are the same regardless of bitness (they use `#if` where needed), so don't worry about having header files loaded from the 64-bit compiler directory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you need to include "windows.h"
before "gl.h"

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "gl.h"
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't change anything, but I'm not sure what the "main" file for this project is, so I'm not sure where exactly I should put it. The project should produce an exe named `fuse.exe` so `fuse.cpp` seemed like the logical place, but that didn't work, and that file doesn't appear to have a main function. The project uses wxWidgets to create its GUI, so I'm guessing maybe the entry point is in some wx header. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Also, searching for similar issues, I noticed a lot of answers are that someone's trying to compile C code as a C++. Is OpenGL C or C++? And how do I change how my project's compiled. I can't actually find anywhere in the entire solution that gl.h is included. I think it's probably brouhgt in by wxWidgets, but again, not sure how.

Comment: OK, I got this working in the end. I just couldn't find any single "top level" cpp file where a single include of windows.h would fix the problem, so I went through the project and included it in every file that was giving me these errors and that stopped them. Getting some other errors now but they seem unrelated. Thanks.