# Linking openGL,GLU and GLUT libraries to VisualC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opengl, glut, glu

Following exactly the steps mentioned here I get 243 errors?!
what's happening?

```
Error   1   error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'glAccum' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   4   error C2182: 'APIENTRY' : illegal use of type 'void'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   6   error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   7   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   8   error C2086: 'int WINGDIAPI' : redefinition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   9   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'glAlphaFunc' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   10  error C2182: 'APIENTRY' : illegal use of type 'void'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   11  error C2086: 'int APIENTRY' : redefinition  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   12  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   13  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GLboolean'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   14  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   15  error C2086: 'int WINGDIAPI' : redefinition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   16  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'glAreTexturesResident'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154    Win32OpenGL 1
Error   17  error C2371: 'APIENTRY' : redefinition; different basic types   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154    Win32OpenGL 1
```

and so on. You see all of the errors occur in gl.h whitch is not implemented by me! 
I have created a win32 application empty project,added to it a source file and I have just these codes yet in the .cpp file.

```
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
#include <gl\glut.h>


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either `#include <windows.h>` or include glut before GL. I am not sure, GLUT is ancient and you shouldn't be using it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

see similar question here: [Sudden issues with glut and glew includes and type specifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166307/sudden-issues-with-glut-and-glew-includes-and-type-specifiers)

and another is here: [Getting many OpenGL Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222509/getting-many-opengl-errors?rq=1)

im my apps I use:

```
#include "gl/glew.h"
#include "gl/wglew.h"
#include "freeglut.h"
```